# navigation bar issue after clicking on card flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[![When I click on any card the navigation bar doesn't work anymore ][2]][2]

**the 1st image shows my navigation bar which works very well. The moment I click on a card the navigation bar doesn't work anymore and I didn't find out what is the reason**

**This is my navigation bar Widget code that I'm using after clicking on the card **

```
class MenuBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
   _State createState() => _State();
 }

class _State extends State<MenuBarWidget> {
  int _index = 0;
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  height: 70,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: AppGradients.linear,
  ),
  child: BottomNavigationBar(
    onTap: (newIndex) => setState(() => _index = newIndex),
    currentIndex: _index,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.white70,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    elevation: 0,
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
        label: 'Principal',
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.assignment_outlined),
        label: 'Pedidos',
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.chat_outlined),
        label: 'Chat',
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
        label: 'Perfil',
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
 }
```

**this is my code after clicking on the card**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
     bottomNavigationBar: MenuBarWidget(),
     appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100),
    child: Stack(children: [
      Container(
        height: 128,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColors.green,
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(
              color: AppColors.blueButton,
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(AppImages.dots),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment(-0.7, -0.3),
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: serviceName,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: AppColors.white,
              fontSize: 25,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment(-0.6, 0.4),
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: 'Confira abaixo todos os profissionais desta categoria',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: AppColors.white,
              fontSize: 9,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]),
  ),
```

**Any help is appreciated thanks **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new list of screens and add the screens you created as the list items

```
List screens = [
HomeScreen();
CarpentryScreen();
...
...
];
```

then make the body of your `MenuBarWidget()` return screens[_index]

```
class MenuBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
   _State createState() => _State();
 }

class _State extends State<MenuBarWidget> {
  int _index = 0;
 
  //  new list of your screens
  List<Widget> screens = [
    PrincipalScreen(),
    PedidosScreen(),
    Chatscreen(),
    Perfilscreen(),
  ];

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // return the screens
  return Scaffold(
  body: screens[_index], 
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    onTap: (newIndex) => setState(() => _index = newIndex),
    currentIndex: _index,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.white70,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    elevation: 0,
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
        label: 'Principal',
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.assignment_outlined),
        label: 'Pedidos',
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.chat_outlined),
        label: 'Chat',
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
        label: 'Perfil',
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
 }
```

then you don't have to add `bottomNavigationBar` to the screens individually, this way, the screen is persistent across all screens